# Can you dynamically create a ConstraintLayout chain?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Basically I have some views and in some cases, I want some views to disappear, and thus the other views' constraints need to be modified and I would like to create a chain between them.  Is this possible?  Also I destroying them?

Comment: Why not do a quick search on Google? First result shows: http://www.zoftino.com/adding-views-&-constraints-to-android-constraint-layout-programmatically You can set what you want in similar way.

Comment: I saw that, but there was close to no mention of chains

Answer (score 1):

`ConstraintSet` is what you are looking for. Specifically, to create a horizontal chain programmatically, you need to look at [`createHorizontalChain()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet.html#createHorizontalChain(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D,%20int)).

> Spaces a set of widgets horizontal between the view startID and endId. Widgets can be spaced with weights.

**Update:** The above link is now deprecated. Use [ConstraintSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintSet#createHorizontalChain(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D,%20int)) in the AndroidX Constraint Layout library instead.

Comment: the link directs to deprecated methods